# Heroku doesn't deploy TypeScript Application

Tags: javascript, typescript, heroku, discord

**Problem**

I've made a typescript discord bot and hosted it on [heroku](https://heroku.com). I get the below error while compiling it and then running it.

- **Error**:

```js
Starting process with command `npm run dev`
State changed from starting to up
Process exited with status 127

> bot@1.0.0 dev
> run-s build start

sh: 1: run-s: not found
State changed from up to crashed
```

- **Procfile**:

```js
worker: npm run dev
```

- **`package.json`**:

```json
// ...
"scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "watch": "tsc -w",
        "start": "node dist/index.js",
        "dev": "run-s build start",
        "watch:start": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node ./dist/index.js\"",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\""
},
"engines": {
        "node": "17.8.0"
}
// ...
```

**Information**

I'm deploying through **Heroku CLI**.

```sh
git push heroku main
```

Comment: `sh: 1: run-s: not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, in the absence of a `Procfile`, Heroku will run your `build` script at build time (when you deploy) and your `start` script as a `web` dyno at runtime (when your dyno starts).

Your `build` and `start` scripts make sense, the former running `tsc` to compile your TypeScript to JavaScript and the latter running the compiled JavaScript.

Since you want to run a `worker` process instead of a `web` process you need a `Procfile`, but this one hands the work off to the wrong script, using `dev` instead of `start`:

```
worker: npm run dev
```

Your `dev` script tries to build your already built application at runtime, which is a problem for a few reasons:

- the immediate issue is that `run-s` is not available, probably [because it was declared as a dev dependency](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation)
- building here is redundant since your application was already compiled during deployment,
- if it works at all, it's going to significantly delay startup every time your dyno restarts, you scale your application, etc.,
- like `run-s`, `tsc` probably isn't available at runtime (and shouldn't be) because it was declared as a dev dependency

Use your `start` script instead of your `dev` script:

```
worker: npm run start
```